# manual installed google sign-in iso sdk terminates app in setting clientID

Tags: ios, google-signin

I manually installed the Google Sign-in SDK (4.0.1), since I use Carthage not cocoapods.
It breaks the App when I set

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "XXX..."
```

I am using Xcode 8.2.1 and Swift 3.

If I uncomment this line, App runs fine. But of course, when I click login view, it breaks again. I guess because the Google Sign-in is not properly initialized yet.

I am stuck here. Please help!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating  Have you  added the configuration file (Google info.plist)  into your project?

Comment: @SaurabhYadav Thanks for checking at this question. I fixed it with the Other Linker Flags settings.

Comment: @Q liu Great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Other Linker Flags were not completely set. I had 2 of 3 sub-settings to -ObjC and the Other Linker Flags reads . Once set them all to -ObjC, things are fixed. Put a screenshot here in case someone else run into this.

[image]